# C# Проблема с IComparable при наследовании

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой

Есть следующий код

```
class A : IComparable<A>, IComparable<B> 
{
        int IComparable<A>.CompareTo(B other)
        {
            //Code
        }

        int IComparable<B>.CompareTo(A other)
        {
            //Code
        }
}

class B : A, IComparable<A>, IComparable<B>
{
        int IComparable<A>.CompareTo(B other)
        {
            //Code
        }

        int IComparable<B>.CompareTo(A other)
        {
            //Code
        }
}

class Program 
{
        static void Main() 
        {
               List<A> a = new List<A>();
               // Заполняем список рандомными элементами А и B 
        } 
}
```

И при попытке отсортировать массив А, элементы сортируются не по правилам, описанным в компараторах.
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Вы не должны явно реализовывать `IComparable<T>`:

```
class A : IComparable<A>
{
    public virtual int CompareTo(A? comparand) => <...>;
}
class B : A, IComparable<B>
{
    public override int CompareTo(A? comparand) =>
        comparand is B b ? CompareTo(b) : -1;
    public virtual int CompareTo(B? comparand) => <...>;
}
```

Не нужно в базовом классе добавлять интерфейс для сравнения наследуемого, сам наследуемый реализует интерфейс.

Для большей ясности пример: в классе `A` есть поле `a` типа `int`. В классе `B` добавили поле `b`. Тогда реализация будет такой:

```
class A : IComparable<A>
{
    public static readonly A Default = new A();

    readonly int a;

    public virtual int CompareTo(A? comparand)
    {
        comparand ??= Default;

        return a.CompareTo(comparand.a);
    }
}
class B : A, IComparable<B>
{
    public static readonly B Default = new B();

    readonly int b;

    public virtual int ComareTo(B? comparand)
    {
        comparand ??= Default;

        var cmp = b.CompareTo(comparand.b);

        if (cmp != 0) return cmp;

        return base.CompareTo(comparand);
    }
    public override int CompareTo(A? comparand) =>
        comparand is B b ? CompareTo(b) :
            (b == 0 ? CompareTo(comparand) : -1);
}
```

```
var a = A.Default;
var b = B.Default;

a.CompareTo(a); // 0
b.CompareTo(a); // 0
a.CompareTo(b); // 0 // так можно, т. к. идёт implicit cast `B` -> `A`
```

Comment: Благодарю покорнейше, действительно помогло!

Comment: @Quel'Thas поставьте пожалуйста галочку возле моего вопроса. так вы его отметите как верный